# Flex arraycollection sorting not working

Tags: string, actionscript-3, apache-flex, sorting, arraycollection

I am trying to sort a list of string stored in an arraycollection. But the sorted result is not correct. Please see my code.

```
spark.collections.Sort

if(value is ArrayCollection){
            var sort:Sort=new Sort();
            var sortField:SortField = new SortField("data")
            sortField.numeric=false;
            sort.fields=[sortField];

            ArrayCollection(value).sort=sort;
            ArrayCollection(value).refresh();
        }
```

Input:  Start With,
Contains,
End With,
Equals IgnoreCase,
Not Equals,
Matching,
Equals

Output: Equals IgnoreCase,
Contains,
End With,
Start With,
Not Equals,
Matching,
Equals

Some time only one row is swapping with another(as above), some time no sorting at all.

Comment: Everything is ok here. You need to provide some more details about your collection. Does the elements in value have values in the data field?

Comment: Just guessing: it's sorted like [alpha, beta, Alpha, Beta] and you want [alpha, Alpha, beta, Beta]?

Comment: @nakib Updated the question. Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case of your array collection having list of string. you need not specify name of SortField your case `data`.

```
            var value:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection(['Start With','Contains','End With','Equals IgnoreCase','Not Equals','Equals']);
            var dataSortField:SortField = new SortField(); //Leave it empty.
            dataSortField.numeric = false;

            var dataSort:Sort = new Sort();
            dataSort.fields=[dataSortField];

            value.sort = dataSort;
            value.refresh();
```

o/p:

```
   "value"  mx.collections.ArrayCollection (@31ced61)   
[0] "Contains"  
[1] "End With"  
[2] "Equals"    
[3] "Equals IgnoreCase" 
[4] "Not Equals"    
[5] "Start With"
```

If arraycollection having object with data property your code is absolutly correct.
like

```
            var value:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
            value.addItem({data:'Start With'});
            value.addItem({data:'Contains'});
            value.addItem({data:'End With'});
            value.addItem({data:'Equals IgnoreCase'});
            value.addItem({data:'Not Equals'});
            value.addItem({data:'Equals'});
```

This case you need to specify like

```
var sortField:SortField = new SortField("data");
```

Comment: I  removed the 'data' attribute and it worked. Thank You @Raja
:)